# Is it possible to roll-up the count of assets on an account?

Tags: custom-field, configuration

I cannot seem to get Assets displayed in the list of available objects when creating a roll-up for the account object. Is it possible to roll-up the count of assets on an  account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It''s not possible to create a standard Roll-Up Summary of Assets on Account.

You can however work around this by writing a trigger which simulates a roll-up, or by using a scheduled job to do this. Another alternative is [Andrew Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett)'s [Declarative Rollups for Lookups](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Answer (score 2):

No, rollups are only available on certain standard relationships and master-detail custom relationships, and assets to accounts is not one of them. Instead, you'll need to resort to a trigger or other Apex Code to rollup the data you're looking for.